# Zlib from python to java

Tags: java, python, zlib

I use this in python:

```
test = zlib.compress(test, 1)
```

And now I want to use this in java, but I don't know how.
At the end I need to convert the result to a string...
I wait your help! thx

Comment: I also don't know how, so I tried googling "java zlib compression". There are a lot of relevant results. Perhaps you could try that and then ask a question if you get stuck.

Comment: I tried this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html but not work

Comment: Then show what you tried and say what happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be more specific in describing what you want to achieve.

Are you just seeking to decompress a zlib-compressed piece of data?
Or are you seeking for a way to exchange data between Python and Java, possibly by transferring it across a network?

For the former, it's basically sticking the compressed datastream in an `Inflater` (not `Deflater`!).  Something like:

```
Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
decompresser.setInput(data);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while (!decompresser.finished()) {
    int size = decompresser.inflate(buffer);
    bos.write(buffer, 0, size);
}
byte[] unzippeddata = bos.toByteArray();
decompresser.end();
```

For the latter, alex's answer already points to Pyro/Pyrolite.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a RPC to create a server.

https://github.com/irmen/Pyro4

And access that server using java.

https://github.com/irmen/Pyrolite